# LOKI C++: How does 'ScatterHierarchyTag' solve the inheritance ambiguity?

Tags: c++, c++-loki

I am going through Chapter 3 of *Alexandrescu's Modern C++ Design.* It explains the implementation of [HierarchyGenerators.h](https://github.com/snaewe/loki-lib/blob/master/include/loki/HierarchyGenerators.h), however changes have been made to the library since then.

I am unable to understand how the `ScatterHierarchyTag` solves the ambiguity in resolving `Field` function (the function allows us to access members defined by particular `Base<type>`, for example `Field<int>(Object)` would get us a `&Base<int>` to `Object`), when the typelist used to generate hierarchy has duplicates. (ex: `GenScatterHierarchy<TYPELIST_4(int,int,string,Widget), Base> Object`) I see that it adds a unique "type/tag" in each of the branches, right before the root `Base<type>` class, but still ambiguity is there right?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Chart showing multiple inheritance issue with repeated types in typelist.
GSH = GenScatterdHierarchy

[image]

I believe the unique tags are inserted seperately, for each of the two connections to `Base<int>` (marked one by blue line) (same goes for other base classes at root)

Also, I inserted picture to make it easier for everyone to understand. Let me know if it does not fit in stackoverflow's guidelines and I shall remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScatterHierarchyTag` is not removing ambiguity. What it does, is making an ambiguous base class accessible.

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A, public B {};
```

Class `C` contains two copies of class `A` (it makes more sense when A is not empty :), one is created because of direct inheritance, another — because of indirect inheritance through `B`. You can access the second instance converting to `B` first:

```
A &indirect_base = static_cast<B>(C_instance);
```

For the other instance, there is simply no way of accessing it. Because of that, it is called "inaccessible base".

This example embeds naturally in class hierarchy created by `GenScatterHierarchy`:

1. `GenScatterHierarchy<int, Base>` is `A`,
2. `GenScatterHierarchy<TYPELIST_3(int,string,Widget)>` is `B`,
3. `GenScatterHierarchy(TYPELIST_4(int,int,string,Widget))` is `C`.

So, instance of `Base<int>` created for the first `int` in type list is an inaccessible base. However, if `ScatterHierarchyTag` is added, we can access it by casting to `GenScatterHierarchy<ScatterHierarchyTag<int, TYPELIST_3(int,string,Widget)>, Base>` first.

Comment: "For the other instance, there is simply no way of accessing it. Because of that, it is called "inaccessible base"." The other instance meaning the one ```C``` got from directly inheriting ```A```? Is it still inaccessible through ```A &direct_base = C_instance;```

Comment: @User10482, exactly. `A &direct_base = C_instance` will not work because it is ambiguous.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you. I had almost given up on getting any good answer to the question. @mizabrik